# .htaccess files, and how they're meant to look?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, malware

I'm currently taking a look at the .htaccess file for my company, in order to add several 301 redirects to it, but it appears as though the file's been corrupted with several dozen injections of malware involving rewrites to other URLs, all starting roughly halfway through the document.

I'd like to return this file to a useable state, but i really do not know if there is such a thing as a vanilla flavoured .htaccess doc that i can safely use, or if i will be compromising the site as it currently exists by simply removing all of the entries in the current file so that it exists as a blank slate?

Comment: [Easy to follow introduction to mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: You're basically going to have to learn the ins and outs of .htaccess, and discover what your .htaccess file is doing. Normally, if a URL Rewrite of some sort involves a domain name or IP address that you can't account for, it's a good bet it's malware. Also find out how someone managed to edit the .htaccess file! You may need to put some controls in the .htaccess to deny access to outsiders, and/or make it read-only once it's settled down.

Comment: Don't blindly clear out/erase an .htaccess file, or use a canned one from who knows where. Presumably yours was originally set up to do specific tasks. Sometimes a specific application will install a generic .htaccess to do certain tasks, but normally there's some customization for your site.